# Error when using PHP exec to run Python script which imports BeautifulSoup

Tags: php, python, exec, beautifulsoup

If I include this line `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` in my script the `exec` returns code 1. If I remove bs4, the script works. And this only happens when I run the script through PHP. No error using command line.

Any thoughts?

I did `sudo pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: You most likely are running the script with the wrong version of python, i,e not the one  sudo pip ... installs for

Comment: When you say "remove bs4" do you mean just `import BeautifulSoup` is left?

Comment: @bmcculley I mean remove the line `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` completely. Currently I uploaded the bs4 folder into the script directory as a work around.

Comment: @Harrison can you show us the code and output? are you actually using BeautifulSoup or just loading it?